# How to change the options of a function (sum()) called inside a function (by()) without giving sum() a specific argument in R

Tags: r

I think this is a simple syntax question but its messing with my brain:

```
data <- data.frame(y=c(1,1,0,NA,1,1),
                   iso3=c(rep("USA",3),rep("RUS",3)),
                   year=rep(1999:2001,2))
```

I simply want to summarize y by year:

```
summarized <- by(data$y,data$year,sum)
```

but without loosing the information in 1999 as happens above. I think this could be done by using `sum(,na.rm = TRUE)` but if I try that in the code above, sum wants an argument. How can I change the specs of `sum` and still use it inside `by` as the function applied to the argument of `by`? I'm very grateful for any hints or how to's!

p.s.: While I'm grateful for any solution, it would be great if you could give me a solution specific to the 'wrapped functions' problem above as its not the first time I run into this problem and I would like to understand it.

Comment: I fixed the way you created the data.frame, as it was completely messed up.

Comment: well... lets say unelegant. It created exactly the same data frame as your version... ;-) But thanks!

Comment: Maybe `aggregate(y ~ year, data, sum)`

Comment: Not really. My fix doesn't throw `Warning in data.frame(y = as.numeric(c(1, 1, 0, "NA", 1, 1)), iso3 = c(rep("USA",  :
  NAs introduced by coercion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
by(data$y,data$year,sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

If we are using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(year) %>% 
     summarise(Sum= sum(y, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks! so the wrapper passes the options on to `sum()`? Could you tell me where is this documented? I always see these "... further arguments to FUN" entries but where are these options collected? Or does this simply mean the arguments which I could give to `sum()` in this case?

Comment: @PeterPan For better understanding you can use anonymous function call. i.e. `by(data$y,data$year, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))`  In the solution, I am avoiding the anonymous call and use the `na.rm=TRUE` directly.